# i having error while using express for api

Tags: node.js, express, syntax-error

[i am having this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYxEq.png)
[this is my app.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3pfd.png)
[this is my products.js file inside routes folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlhSL.png)
[this is my products.js file inside controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESnMx.png)

i tried FOR Windows

1. Go to the task manager
2. Then look for Node.js: Server-side JavaScript
3. Then right click on it and End task from the processes.
   i am not able to find any syntactical error at 7:2 in routes/products.js file

Comment: You have not putted semicolons there on line number 7

Comment: but sir this is javascript it forgive us if we don't add semicolons in our code,

Comment: please sir help me this error irritates me every time on this code

Comment: and same error continues on adding the semicolon

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)